# authenticating json data, it does not take username and password in swift? can you correct me my code?

Tags: ios, json, authentication, swift3

http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/E1jKVbplX                      I have registered successfully. i am struck in authentication. i accessed all data. but i struck in accessing individual user data. please see below code and correct me.                                                        var email = “bhupal”
        var pwd  = “k”

```
    //
    let parameters: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["Email": email as AnyObject, "Password": pwd as AnyObject,"Type" : "Organization" as AnyObject,"Mode" : "Register" as AnyObject]

    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/E1jKVbplX  ")! //change the url
           let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as GET



    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(myJson)
                    print("--------")
                    print(myJson[0])
                    print(myJson[1])
                    print("--------")

                    email = myJson["Email"] as? String
                    pwd = myJson["Password"]  as? String
                    print("--------")

                    print(email)
                    print(pwd)


                    print("--------")

                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: `myJson` is a `Array`. So why should `myJson["Email"]` be working? That's for a Dict. `myJson[0]["Email"]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is **Array of Dictionary** so `myJson[0]` will return you a dictionary object and in that dictionary you should try accessing value for `Email` or `Password`. 
You can try below code to access email and password :

```
for dict in myJson { // myJson is array and dict will of dictionary object

  let email = dict[Email]
  let password = dict[Password]

  print("--------")
  print("Email is : \(email)")
  print("Password is : \(password)")
  print("--------")
}
```

**Note** : You make need to improvise it.